# I can't change the text of a UILabel in Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am trying to change the text of a UILabel in my code, but the text won't change.

I tried to use the well-known command for changing the text, "NameOfLabel.text = 'Hello", but that did not work. So I tried to put it in a start function so you would click a UIButton and it would change the text, didn't work either.

```
@IBOutlet var nameOfRobot: UILabel!
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any){
    let nameNumber = Int.random(in: 1...3)


    if nameNumber == 1 {
        self.nameOfRobot.text = "Ben"
    }

    if nameNumber == 2 {
        self.nameOfRobot.text = "Oliver"
    }

    if nameNumber == 3 {
        self.nameOfRobot.text = "Colton"
    }
}
```

I want it to choose a number between 1 and three and have it change the `UILabel` to that name. When I start the app though, it works, but it doesn't change the text of the label.

Comment: Please call your vars and lets and functions with a lowercase letter. Only Types use an uppercase letter.

Comment: Is the `startButton` function running at all? If you put `print("Start Button Function")` in there do you see that appearing in the console?

Comment: No- the function doesn't print anything. It does say it is connected from the storyboard to the view controller though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to connect the action to the button press:

[image: storyboard]

You can tell this is done correctly by looking at the full circle indicator in the editor:

[image: editor]

EDIT: Setting the correct class to the viewController in the storyboard:

[image: setting the vc class]

Comment: Oh, the circles were empty, it looks like the code wasn't connected. When I Ctrl+Drag the code to the storyboard, it doesn't want to connect. It doesn't even highlight an area where it could connect to. Is this a bug in Xcode?

Comment: @Piie. It is almost never a bug in Xcode. Have you correctly set the subclass of your view controller?

Comment: In that case, probably the storyboard controller does not know which type it is, so you need to provide the type in the storyboard, take a look at the edit

Comment: So I added the subclass (it was empty) and it still wouldn't connect. I even clicked the little arrow icon on the right of the subclass name and it brought me to the correct viewcontroller to show it was working.

Comment: At this point, just try restarting Xcode, it should work. Try just right or alt clicking the button and seeing if you can connect it that way.